# How to Add Function Returns as Key-Values in Every Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, object

I have multiple functions that calculate values in an array of objects.  I am trying to run the functions through all 7,200 objects in my array, and in turn add the return of those functions as a new Key-Value pair in each object.  Below is a sample with a 5 object array instead of a 7200 object array.

I am new to JavaScript and am not sure how solve this.  I can access the "Status" of each object using the const currentDay = myData.at(-1), console log the result and manually insert it as a new Key-Value Pair in the last object, change currentDay to (-2) etc.  As I have 7000+ objects to do this with, I am looking for a way to not do this manually.  I want my resulting new Array to look like this:

```
const myData2 = [
  {
    Date: "1990-02-09",
    End: "500",
    PreviousEnd: "480",
    NextEnd: "515",
    Status: ["Positive 2 Day", "Next Day Up"],
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-10",
    End: "515",
    PreviousEnd: "500",
    NextEnd: "505",
    Status: ["Positive 1 Day", "Next Day Down"],
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-11",
    End: "505",
    PreviousEnd: "515",
    NextEnd: "530",
    Status: ["Negative", "Next Day Up"],
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-12",
    End: "530",
    PreviousEnd: "525",
    NextEnd: "555",
    Status: ["Positive 2 Day", "Next Day Up"],
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-13",
    End: "555",
    PreviousEnd: "530",
    NextEnd: "570",
    Status: ["Positive 2 Day", "Next Day Up"],
  },
];
```

This is my current code.

```js
const myData = [
  {
    Date: "1990-02-09",
    End: "500",
    PreviousEnd: "480",
    NextEnd: "515",
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-10",
    End: "515",
    PreviousEnd: "500",
    NextEnd: "505",
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-11",
    End: "505",
    PreviousEnd: "515",
    NextEnd: "530",
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-12",
    End: "530",
    PreviousEnd: "525",
    NextEnd: "555",
  },
  {
    Date: "1990-02-13",
    End: "555",
    PreviousEnd: "530",
    NextEnd: "570",
  },
];

const currentDay = myData.at(-1);

const endUpDown = (function () {
  if (
    currentDay.End > currentDay.PreviousEnd &&
    currentDay.End > currentDay.NextEnd
  ) {
    return "Positive 1 Day";
  } else if (
    currentDay.End > currentDay.PreviousEnd &&
    currentDay.End < currentDay.NextEnd
  ) {
    return "Positive 2 Day";
  } else {
    return "Negative";
  }
})();

const nextDayUp = (function () {
  if (currentDay.End < currentDay.NextEnd) {
    return "Next Day Up";
  } else {
    return "Next Day Down";
  }
})();

const currentStatus = [endUpDown, nextDayUp];

console.log(currentStatus);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all the parts, you just need to reshuffle them to make them callable from within a `map()` call. All I've done is make your [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)s into named functions with a parameter `currentDay` which expects an object rather than calling them on a global `currentDay` as in your example.

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call simply clones the passed object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) and then adds the `status` property as a tuple of your two function calls.

```js
const myData = [{ Date: '1990-02-09', End: '500', PreviousEnd: '480', NextEnd: '515', }, { Date: '1990-02-10', End: '515', PreviousEnd: '500', NextEnd: '505', }, { Date: '1990-02-11', End: '505', PreviousEnd: '515', NextEnd: '530', }, { Date: '1990-02-12', End: '530', PreviousEnd: '525', NextEnd: '555', }, { Date: '1990-02-13', End: '555', PreviousEnd: '530', NextEnd: '570', },];

function endUpDown(currentDay) {
  if (
    currentDay.End > currentDay.PreviousEnd &&
    currentDay.End > currentDay.NextEnd
  ) {
    return 'Positive 1 Day';
  } else if (
    currentDay.End > currentDay.PreviousEnd &&
    currentDay.End < currentDay.NextEnd
  ) {
    return 'Positive 2 Day';
  } else {
    return 'Negative';
  }
}

function nextDayUp(currentDay) {
  if (currentDay.End < currentDay.NextEnd) {
    return 'Next Day Up';
  } else {
    return 'Next Day Down';
  }
}

const result = myData.map((currentDay) => ({
  ...currentDay,
  status: [endUpDown(currentDay), nextDayUp(currentDay)],
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works great!!  I was closer than I was thinking.  I appreciate you solving this!